# How to specify Binding XPath using property element syntax?

Tags: wpf

I need to apply an `XPath Binding` for `ItemsSource` of an `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. The XPath binding is working correct when applied using property attribute syntax, but in a case, I have very long XPath expression to use and so I thought to apply it using property element syntax.

This is what is working using the Property Attribute Syntax:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate
            x:Key="rootTemplate"
            ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=./*}">
            <StackPanel
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="5,0,0,0"
                    Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <Image
                    Source="repeat.ico"
                    Margin="5 0 0 0"
                    Width="20"
                    Height="20"
                    Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource RepeatToVisiblityConverter}}"></Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

And this is what I am trying to achieve for the same template above, using the Property Element syntax when using the long XPath: [Although I have used the same XPath here in question, but in real it is long]

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate
            x:Key="rootTemplate">
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                <Binding>
                    <Binding.XPath>
                        <![CDATA[./*]]>
                    </Binding.XPath>
                </Binding>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <CheckBox
                            Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                        <TextBlock
                            Margin="5,0,0,0"
                            Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

The ItemsSource becomes empty and nothing is shown when using this syntax for specifying the Binding.

Does anyone know, how to fix this?

Comment: How about `<Binding.XPath>./*</Binding.XPath>`?

Comment: Or `<Binding XPath="./*" />`?

Comment: This also does not work. And even if this works, I have a very large XPath expression that will need many escape sequences if written in double quotes.

Comment: There are no double quotes in the first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works:

It just removes these two lines from above:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
```

I will find out later, why removing this works.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate
            x:Key="rootTemplate">
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                <Binding>
                    <Binding.XPath>
                        ./*[@Repeat="true" or .//*[@Repeat="true"]]
                    </Binding.XPath>
                </Binding>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
            <StackPanel
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <CheckBox
                    Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="5,0,0,0"
                    Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```